# Do not know python, but when asked for input if i just press enter it breaks the program, how can i use a value error to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
from random import randrange
#imports necessary modules
global score
score = 0


def question():
    qno = 0
    while(qno<10):
        num1 = randrange(1,12)
        num2 = randrange(1,10)
        operator = ['*','+','-']
        ems = random.choice(operator)
        ans = (int(eval(str(num1) + ems + str(num2))))
        print (num1, ems, num2)
        userans = int(input ("What is the answer?"))
        if userans == ans:
            print ("Correct!")
            global score
            score += 1
        elif userans != ans:
            print("Not Quite")

        else:
            raise ValueError()
        qno += 1

question()
print (score,"/10")
```

Comment: We can't debug your code that asks for input, because you didn't post the code that asks for input. [mcve] please.

Comment: Please show all your code including the `input` line

Comment: Trying, I edited it so that all my code is there.

Comment: Look up the `operator` module. That `(int(eval(str(num1) + operator + str(num2))))` is a complete mess. Map the operator strings to their corresponding functions in the operator module, and call those on the ints directly. There are questions all over SO doing this that you can use as a guide.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Seconding that. `eval` is code smell, and a strong one at that. 99.9% of the time, you want to use `ast.literal_eval` (for those cases where you're trying to handle rereading `repr`s of Python literals) or the various `operator` operators-as-functions functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of this solution?

```
qno,score = 0,0
while(qno<10):

    num1 = randrange(1,12)
    num2 = randrange(1,10)
    operator = ['*','+','-']
    ems = random.choice(operator)
    ans = (int(eval(str(num1) + ems + str(num2))))
    print (num1, ems, num2)
    try:
        userans = int(input ("What is the answer?"))
    except ValueError:
        print('skipped')
        userans=ans-1
    if userans == ans:
        print ("Correct!")
        global score
        score += 1

    elif userans != ans:
        print("Not Quite")

    else:
        raise ValueError()


    qno += 1
```

You can modify the code under except ValueError, I've just inserted a code that consider pressing enter a "wrong answer"

Comment: Thanks for the help, saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you press enter, an empty string is passed and `int()` cannot parse a empty string.

Instead try:

```
try:
    userans = int(input ("What is the answer?"))
except ValueError:
    print("enter an integer!")
```

Comment: Probably want this in a while loop

Comment: I actually added my answer before OP edited adding the whole code but then again it is clearly obvious that this code should be added to the point where the variable `userans` is asked for.

Comment: The OP's while loop is for controlling the question numbers. It loops to 10 and increments at the end. This should be in a `while True:` loop and `break` on successful input, or `while userans is not None` and set it to `None` in the `except` block, or similar, in order to keep asking for input until valid input is given. Otherwise, bad input would skip the rest of the question!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a `try/except` block you can just use an if statement

```
userans = input ("What is the answer?")
if userans.isdigit():
    userans = int(user_input)
else:
    print("That's not a number")
```

Comment: My comment on @KDawg's answer applies to you, too. If you don't put this construct in a `while` loop, then bad input will skip the rest of the question, which is probably not desired.